# Rounding a range

Tags: code-golf, math, number

You have a line with two endpoints `a` and `b` (`0 ≤ a < b`) on a 1D space. When `a` or `b` has a fractional value, you want to round it to an integer.

One way to do this is to round `a` and `b` each to its nearest integer, but this has a problem that the length of the rounded range (`L`) can vary while `b - a` stays the same. For example,

```
b - a = 1.4
(a, b) = (1, 2.4) -> (1, 2), L = 1
         (1.2, 2.6) -> (1, 3), L = 2
```

We want to find a way to round `(a, b)` so that `L` always has the same value `⌊b - a⌋` while the rounded pair `(ra, rb)` is closest to `(a, b)`.

With `(a, b) = (1.2, 2.6)`, we can consider two candidates of `(ra, rb)` with `L = ⌊2.6 - 1.2⌋ = 1`. One is `(1, 2)` and the other is `(2, 3)`. `(1, 2)`'s overlapping range with `(a, b) = (1.2, 2.6)` is `(1.2, 2)`, while `(2, 3)` overlaps at `(2, 2.6)`. `(1, 2)` has a larger overlapping range (`(1.2, 2)` vs `(2, 2.6)`), so in this case we choose `(1, 2)`.

Sometimes there are two options with the same overlapping length. For example, `(0.5, 1.5) -> (0, 1), (1, 2)`. In such cases, either could be, but one should be, chosen.

#### Examples

```
0 ≤ a < b
b - a ≥ 1
(a, b) -> (ra, rb)

(1, 2) -> (1, 2)
(1, 3.9) -> (1, 3)
(1.1, 4) -> (2, 4)
(1.2, 4.6) -> (1, 4)
(1.3, 4.7) -> (1, 4) or (2, 5)
(1.4, 4.8) -> (2, 5)
(0.5, 10.5) -> (0, 10) or (1, 11)
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to have a test case with L > 1.

Comment: IMHO it's strange that the rounded range's length is actually the truncation of the original range's length. Surely it should have been rounded too?

Comment: @chunes Done...

Comment: @Neil If the length of the rounded range is also rounded, the half-points in the rounded range may not be included in the original range. Consider rounding (0.7, 2.3), if you also round the resulting length the result will include 2 half-points while the original has 1 (1.5). Keeping the number of half-points the same could be useful when applying this to some computer graphic operation.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 44 bytes

```
lambda a,b:(m:=(a+b+1-(l:=int(b-a)))//2,m+l)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY5NCsIwEIX3PcXgasamVav4U6gncZNii4E0CbUKLryFOzeC6J28jR0jWt1kHt97eTPnuzs0G2su1zJb3XZNGc0fQssqX0uQIk-xSjOUYR6OItRppkyDeSSJaDBIRBVqev85lrYGDcqAdYXBIcV1IddamWKLlAaghIUMdLx1WjXYg2gJPQqAof3AtoKhEn3mlXRY7KUWyIBaw9W8X4kS-4r8-9r4PuLyOOFIQELc7lXwGvHiF8WtGHuUsGKUcG76l2O3A31yzMlZJ8l3f4smbM877f64Jw)

### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 50 bytes

```
lambda a,b:(m:=(a+b+~(l:=int(b-a))%2)//2-l//2,m+l)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY5BbsIwEEX3OcUICWmGOKEY1NJI4STdOCJRLU1sKwQkFu0puusGqaJ34jbNYETTbsaj97___M_vcOxfvTt9NeXLed832fqi2bTV1oBRVYFtUaJJq_QduSit67HKDNFU03yuMx6GalOm28-3xnfAYB34UDt8oLyrzZatq3dIRQJWeSiB811g2-MEsg1MKAGB_g6HCIFWzYS3JmB9MKxQAA1C6KSGVQ3OLMV5vXgrcbp84EKBJkmPW3J98ue_KB-WZURaNkFafI__fKKOYHQuxfk0ckrv36CVyOtReiz3Aw)

### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 56 bytes

```
lambda a,b:((m:=(a+b+~(l:=int(b-a))%2)//2)-l//2,m--l//2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY5BasMwEEX3PsUQKMwkktPIIXEN7kmykYlNBLIkHLfQRXuK7roJlOZOuU09VkjdbGaG97--_tc5vPUH707fTbn7eekbmV9yq9tqr0GLqkBsixL1olp8oC1K43qspCZ6ULRcKpJ2mKKV46br-_fGd2DBOPChdvhIaVfrvTWuPiIVCRjhoQSbHoM1Pc5APsOMEmDob3CIYGjEnHmrA9av2gpkQIMQOu5iRINzQ3GOP15LnC6fuBKgiNPjlYwrffqP0uHIIlJ8MVLs29z5WJ3A6MzYuZ04ufdf0JrlfJIey_0C)

### How?

The basic idea is: If the required length `l` is even round the midpoint and move `l/2` in both directions. If `l` is odd round the midpoint to the nearest half integer instead.

Comment: I don't understand this. How does `m` (and thus `m+l`) end up being an integer? It seems to me that it should be a non-integer if either `a` or `b` are non-integers.

Comment: @chunes Well, it's an integer valued float in that case because of floor division (`//2`).

Comment: Ah, it really looked to me like the integer division is outside the assignment expression to `m`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 44 bytes

```
[ 2dup - ⌊ -rot 1 + + over - 2 /i tuck + ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdBLCsIwEAbgfU/xIxSUWDX1rQcQN27ElbooMbGlmpQ83IgXEE/pRWq0iDYDw8zHvxgiEmaVLjfr5WoxQ2KMYgY515KfcE5s@mkdJzOmDhwmdUKcOITS3m0mj5gHwTWAf1fEoLh9ZzLt0t4f9EEJfdMvMfokSFzXcaX9uk4qHfwr7ZHhex9WeAvKLeKDKxDh@bgj0sr6A4gvdeHaa4xuButY7mnvw41m6NoIXWsnGyh0Jq3AHkydC2V49RkRT1havgA)

Takes input as `b a`. Port of loopy walt's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246945/97916).

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
O>I`αï©-2÷D®+‚
```

-2 bytes porting [*@loopyWalt*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246945/52210); make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//08@SWDOscOvwqktMsO3RMKuK@KAmv//WzEuMiwyLjZd) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/f7vKhHMbD68/tFLX6PB2l0PrtB81zPqv8z862lDHKFYHROpZgmg9Qx1jMG0EFDEDs4yBLHMwywTIsgCyDPRMdQz1TGNjAQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
O              # Sum the (implicit) input-pair
 >             # Increase it by 1
  I            # Push the input-pair again
   `           # Pop and push both values separated to the stack
    α          # Take the absolute difference between both
     ï         # Cast it to an integer to floor it
      ©        # Sort this value in variable `®` (without popping)
       -       # Subtract it from the earlier sum+1
        2÷     # Integer-divide it by 2
          D    # Duplicate this
           ®+  # Add `®` to the copy
             ‚ # Pair the two values together
               # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 34 bytes

```
f(a,b)=[m=(a+b+1-l=(b-a)\1)\2,m+l]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc5BCsIwEAXQqwxZJWQSTFq1LupF2iBToVJISyjtwrO46UY8k7cxMbqZ_wYG_jxegebhcgvb9lyXXlVv1nPCTtTNWHOSnTTK17xTJFojWouj9O53uVII_s4J1BnCPExLJEsLgyt5z3sEEgKhaQyCdRExC336SkeXWTZKH7KL5GN2mVwl7_QewcTpnMjl_3c_)

A port of [loopy walt's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246945/97916).

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 48 bytes

```
f(a,b)=[a,b]\1+if(a%1>b%1,[1,0],[t=a%1+b%1>1,t])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc7NCoMwDADgVwmCYDEWq25zB_siXRlx4BCKFKmHPcsuXsaeaW-zdM5L8iWQn-fb0zxe735dX0sYivZTDhlhLzrD0V5UPnKdKt2nCo3C0qIJHTdybmiFwYr_3ELeu0dGUGjw8zgFZhKLBG7kXDYgkBAIhrdAZRmca3n-SbKbTRVLHjfX0afNTXQbXcoDguJo9-P7818)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 62 bytes

```
f(a,b)=(A,\floor(b-a)+A)+\{\ceil(b)-b<a-A,0\}(1,1)
A=floor(a)
```

Takes input as function parameters and returns a point `(ra,rb)`

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vc9xlo3gjp)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

After messing around trying to find an arithmetic solution I came up with the following:

```
Ｎθ≔Ｅ⁺Ｎ⟦±θ⊕θ⟧⌊ιηＩ÷⟦↨η±¹Ση⟧²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy7CoMwFIZ3nyLjOZAKcSo49YLgUBE6ikOqBxOI0ebi66cpdOj2Xz6@SUk3bdKk1No9hi6uL3Lwxrq4eK8XCw@5Q2@ih/8fORs6WmSgjHLW2snRSjbQnPuYl8ZsmwONOars6p22AW7Sh6wJd33omWC4Sk@gOPuZxJd@xhUUjpxViFinJEpRVOU5nQ7zAQ) Link is to verbose version of code.

Rather than trying to be clever with vectorised arithmetic, I rewrote it to use variables instead. It still came out at 26 bytes:

```
ＮθＮη≔⌊⁻ηθζ≧⁺⊕θηＩ÷⟦⁻ηθ⁺ηζ⟧²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw9C4MwFEV3f0XG9yAVdCo4lZZCBkW6lg6pBhOIT82Hg38@Vbq43cO993Raum6SNiVBcwxNHL/KwYJVdma98817MxA87TQ5qA1FD5qzBZGzba9rOf8XLzPoAK2NnjNBnVOjoqD63cnZ4WmdoQB36QMICg@zml7B@yTk7DgfecMPZyUiVikVeZGV@TVdVvsD) Link is to verbose version of code.

A direct port of @loopywalt's Python answer turns out to also be 26 bytes:

```
ＮθＮη≔⌊⁻ηθζ≔÷⁻⊕⁺ηθζ²εＩ⟦ε⁺εζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oLmZ8B5DsWF2em52m45eTnF2n4ZuaVFmtk6CgUamrqKFQhpD3zSlwyyzJTUqFKPPOSi1JzU/NKUlM0AnJQ9OgoGAFxKlBvQFFmXomGc2JxiUZ0qo4CWF0qSEmspqb1//@GeoZcRnoW/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Note that because it does the integer division by 2 earlier it doesn't need to explicitly close the output list, saving a byte.